# Xamarin Forms - Close view after successful login with Azure AD

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm successfully logging in my Xamarin Forms application with Azure AD.
The problem is that when I'm logged in through the webview opened by default with :

```
user = await AuthenticationManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, true);
```

The created webview shows a message telling me that I'm logged in but I don't know how to close this view after that.

Is there an event I can use or am I doing something wrong and the webview is supposed to close itself upon complete authentication ?

EDIT :

I changed my call to :

```
user = await AuthenticationManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, false);
```

Becase I didn't give an SID being a Xamarin Forms project.
The result is that the window closes now but I get and InvalidOperationException with the message :

> Invalid format of the authentication response.

Any idea about the format I should give ? I don't see what I could change to be able to get the user  connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just leave off the true/false on the end.

For more information on authentication, see chapter 2 of http://aka.ms/zumobook

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried that but unfortunately the result is the same.
I'm guessing it is more an Azure configuration issue rather than a code issue.
I'm reading the part you suggested and will try to change something if I find any new piece of information.

Comment: Hi, it seems like I have an issue I can't locate.
My app seems to have been correctly registered in the Azure AD.
I am able to log in from the web browser.
The webview that opens in the app dissapears but i still get the "Invalid format of the authentication response."
Any insights about how to deal with this ?
Thanks

Comment: All right, sorry for the triple comment.
I started my configuration back from scratch and it is working now.